# UserProvider not implementing correct interface

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, fosoauthserverbundle

I am trying to use a custom UserProvider with the FOS User bundle package and the FOS Oauth package. I have been following this tutorial http://blog.tankist.de/blog/2013/07/17/oauth2-explained-part-2-setting-up-oauth2-with-symfony2-using-fosoauthserverbundle/.

When I try and register my new user service I am getting the following error

`UserProvider::__construct() must implement interface Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository, array given`

UserProvider:

```
UserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
/**
 * @var ObjectRepository
 */
protected $userRepository;

/**
 * @param ObjectRepository $userRepository
 */
public function __construct(ObjectRepository $userRepository)
{
    $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
}

/**
 * @param string $username
 * @return mixed
 */
public function loadUserByUsername($username)
{ ... }
```

UserRepository

`class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements ObjectRepository`

services.yml

```
parameters:
  entity_name:  Hornby\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository

services:
  user_provider_me:
  class: Hornby\UserBundle\Provider\UserProvider
  arguments:
    name: [%entity_name%]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your services.yml file is wrong. I'm not really sure what you want to achieve but you pass array

```
arguments:
    name: [%entity_name%] #entity_name is just a string
```

as an argument to `UserProvider` class. Constructor of this class expects `ObjectRepository` and this is your problem here.

A translation of services.xml from link you provided should look rather like that:

```
parameters:
    platform.entity.user.class: Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\User
    platform.user.provider.class: Acme\DemoBundle\Provider\UserProvider
services:
    platform.user.manager:
        class: Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
        factory: ["@doctrine", getManagerForClass]
        arguments: [%platform.entity.user.class%]

    platform.user.repository:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Repository\UserRepository
        factory: ["@platform.user.manager", getRepository]
        arguments: [%platform.entity.user.class%]

    platform.user.provider:
        class: %platform.user.provider.class%
        arguments: [@platform.user.repository]
```